# Trimble-Connect Selecting attribute

Tags: c#, .net, .net-4.8

I am writing a extension for Trimble-Connect appliaction in c# (.net 4.8). I'd like to get list of elements whose contain specified name like "3WD".

```
public void SerachObjects(Project project)
            {
                project.ModelObjectManager.SetSelected(false);



                var modelContainsParams = project.ModelObjectManager.GetModelObjects().Where(x => x.GetAttributeNames().ToList().Any()).ToList();


                if(modelContainsParams.Any())
                {
                    project.ModelObjectManager.SetSelected(true, modelContainsParams);
                }
            }
```

In this method I have a list of elements that contain parameters details in Visualizator like: ModelObject, ModelObject.ProjectIdentifier etc. But it is not what i am looking for.

I'd like to reffer to other attribute in trimble connection which is called "IfcBuildingElementProxyType" whose have parameter called "Name" and detail: "3DWB_002S".

How can I reffer to this attribute ?

I was trying some methods but anything work as I want.